# getJSON not working in Cordova 2.1.0 on iOS

Tags: json, cordova

I'm developing a Phonegap app for iOS. I'm new to both!

Anyway, it's looking good, but I can't get the following JSON call to run. It doesn't get to the server - there's nothing in the logs.

I get the 'in' alert but not the 'out' alert.

The code works fine from a standard web page.

I have included

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

I've added * to the ExternalHosts of Cordova.plist as found on the mighty Google!

What have I missed?

Thanks.

```
function GetData(){
  alert('in');
  $.getJSON('http://dev.myurl.com/brief/getdata.php', function(data)
              {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                       alert(val.itemValue);               
                }) // each
              }// function
            );//getjson
   alert('out');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already tried this:

```
function GetData(){
    alert('in');
    $.get('http://dev.myurl.com/brief/getdata.php', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
               alert(val.itemValue);               
        })
    }), 'json';
    alert('out');
}
```

Comment: No - only what's in my original post. Seems to be working now - I'd forgotten to include ajax, and when I did hadn't tested it int the simulator. The actual  iPad needed some settings changed to allow web access for developer stuff. Real PITA !!